# How to add link to video title if artist?

Tags: php, string, function

Let's say i have:

```
$string = '2Pac - Dear Mama';
```

and the db like this:

```
id - some number
artist_name - 2Pac
alternative_name - Tupac
artist_slug - 2pac
```

How to transform the string to something like:

```
<a href="//example.com/artist/2pac/">2Pac</a> - Dear Mama
```

even if the $string would be:

```
$string = 'Tupac - Dear Mama';
```

transform it to:

```
<a href="//example.com/artist/2pac/">Tupac</a> - Dear Mama
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

// later edit

I already use this function but i was wondering how to check if the artist has more names and keep the same page

```
function artist_name($title){ global $site_url;
$words = explode("-", $title); $result = array();
foreach ($words as $word){
$word = trim($word);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `artist_name` FROM `artists` WHERE `artist_name` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($word) . "' LIMIT 0, 1;");
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){$result[] = '<a href="'.$site_url.'artist/'.clean_slug_function($word).'/" title="'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a>';}
else{$result[] = $word;}}
$result = implode($result, " - ");
return $result;}
```

// i've done it like this:

```
function artist_name($title){ global $site_url;
$words = explode("-", $title); $result = array();
foreach ($words as $word){
$word = trim($word);
$sql = dbquery("SELECT `artist_slug` FROM `artists` WHERE `artist_name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($word)."' OR `alternative_name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($word)."' LIMIT 0, 1;");
while($row = dbarray($sql)){$artist_slug = $row['artist_slug'];}
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){$result[] = '<a href="'.$site_url.'artist/'.clean_slug_function($artist_slug).'/" title="'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a>';}
else{$result[] = $word;}}
$result = implode($result, " - ");
return $result;}
```

Example:

for

```
$title = 'Tupac - Dear Mama';
echo artist_name($title);
```

the result will be

```
<a href="http://example.com/artist/2pac/" title="Tupac">Tupac</a> - Dear Mama
```

*notice `2pac` url slug vs. `Tupac` (not `2Pac`) name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
" - " can be used as delimiter to divide the string in 2 parts. Contents of the string are put into an array.
More on explode function - [on php.net](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$string = 'Tupac - Dear Mama';
$string2 = explode(' - ',$string);
echo "<a href='//example.com/artist/2pac/'>" . $string2[0] . "</a> - " . $string2[1];
```

2.
I assume you have 2 tables, one with artists, and one with songs.

artists:

- id
- artist_name
- alternative_name
- artist_slug

songs:

- id
- artistid
- title

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM artists, songs WHERE songid = 1 AND artists.id = songs.artistid";    
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<a href='//example.com/artist/" . $row['artist_name'] . "/'>" . $row['artist_name'] . "</a> - " . $row['title'];
```

3.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `artist_name` FROM `artists` WHERE `artist_name` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($word) . "' OR alternative_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($word) . "' LIMIT 0, 1;");
```

Comment: but how to do that using the data from mysql?

Comment: Added how to create links with data from MySQL.

Comment: no, i have not :( Using my actual function (please see the edit) i count only on the video/song title.

Comment: So, you have a combination of artist name and song title, for example - tupac - dear mama. You want to search for artist names similar to tupac in database and return their songs? That's what you want to do?

Comment: not really, i want to check if the video title has an artist name in it from the `artists` table.

- if it has (checking both `artist_name` and `alternative_name` ), transform the title into a link (just like in my example) with the `artist_slug` from the db.
- if it does not, just echo that title

Comment: Added OR condition to check for artist_names and alternative_names. If that's not what you need, please rephrase the question and clearly say what is working, what is not, do you get an error message etc. This is third time I'm answering. I created a db with 2 tables just to check, and everything is working as I'd expect.

Comment: i solved the problem using the code above (see my edit). thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)